# How to ensure structural modifications to Hibernate entities are consistent with each other?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, annotations, validation

I need to make some structural modifications to an existing set of Hibernate entity classes. E.g. adding new fields, removing fields, adding/changing relationships etc.

My first approach was to just go in and make the changes manually in the classes.

But this seems a bit of an error-prone approach when making multiple modifications - for example, a `@OneToMany` has a corresponding `@ManyToOne` relationship in a different class - if lots of updates are made it would be easy for some of these to be missed.

Is there a tool I could be using to update the classes? Or, failing that, is there a tool or "strict mode" that could validate whether updates have been made in all the right places - e.g. the code still compiles and builds if a `@ManyToOne` is missed but it would be nice to be picked up on this.

Comment: What are the structural changes you need to apply? Could you give some examples?

Comment: E.g. adding new fields and removing existing fields. Some of the added/removed fields involve `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` relationships to other entities.